# Recyclerview not displaying items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

Before setting the dataset to the adapter, I am getting the dataset from the Room database, and then I set the data to the adapter and set the adapter to the recyclerview. Currently there are 2 items in the list. From my logs I see that all methods are getting called for the first item in the list but not for the second, and no items or views are being displayed onto the screen. I am not sure what is happening can someone help me spot the issue? Thanks in advance for your help.

goals_content.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/goals_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:dividerHeight="1px"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

    <!--view to show if the dataset is empty-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyElement"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:text="No Goals Added"
        android:textColor="#525252"
        android:textSize="19sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

GoalsActivity.java

```
GoalsRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
RecyclerView goalsListView;
....

goalsListView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.goals_list);

....

private void createGoalsList() {

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Goal>>(){

            @Override
            protected List<Goal> doInBackground(Void... params) {
                List<Goal> returnedGoals = goalDao.getAllGoals();
                return returnedGoals;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<Goal> returnedGoals) {

                //check your goals list is empty or not
                if(returnedGoals.size() > 0){

                    //make the goals list visible if there is data
                    goalsListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    noGoalsTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    //set array adapter for the goals list
                    adapter = new GoalsRecyclerViewAdapter(returnedGoals);
                    goalsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }else{

                    //if there is no data display empty list text.
                    goalsListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    noGoalsTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }.execute();
    }
```

GoalsRecyclerviewAdapter.java

```
public class GoalsRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GoalsRecyclerViewAdapter.GoalsViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = GoalsRecyclerViewAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private List<Goal> mGoals;

    public GoalsRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Goal> goals) {
        Log.d(TAG, "adapter initialized");
        mGoals = goals;
    }

    @Override
    public GoalsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder: inside");
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.goal_row, parent, false);
        return new GoalsViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(GoalsViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: position " + position);
        holder.bind(mGoals.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getItemCount: " + mGoals.size());
        return mGoals.size();
    }

    class GoalsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView goalsLabel, goalCount;

        GoalsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            goalsLabel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.calls_goal_label);
            goalCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.goal_count);
        }

        void bind(Goal goal){
            Log.d(TAG, "bind: " + goal.toString());
            goalsLabel.setText(goal.getGoalTitle());
            goalCount.setText(String.valueOf(goal.getGoalTarget()));
        }
    }

    public List<Goal> getGoals(){
        return mGoals;
    }

    public void setGoals(List<Goal> goals){
        mGoals = goals;
    }
}
```

UPDATED: added row layout
goal_row.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ubcma.leadster.activity.GoalsActivity"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/calls_goal_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        tools:text="@string/calls_per_week"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/goal_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        tools:text="4"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

logs

```
09-27 23:10:08.071 1606-1818/? D/ActivityManager: resumeTopActivityInnerLocked() : #1 prevTask=TaskRecord{46a33bdd0 #6227 A=com.ubcma.leadster U=0 StackId=1 sz=2} next=ActivityRecord{8396555d0 u0 com.ubcma.leadster/.activity.GoalsActivity t6227} mFocusedStack=ActivityStack{43432a4d0 stackId=1, 38 tasks}
09-27 23:10:08.128 24667-24667/com.ubcma.leadster D/ViewRootImpl@14dce6f[GoalsActivity]: setView = DecorView@be0e77c[GoalsActivity] touchMode=true
09-27 23:10:08.211 1606-4253/? D/WindowManager: finishDrawingWindow: Window{94ca436d0 u0 com.ubcma.leadster/com.ubcma.leadster.activity.GoalsActivity} mDrawState=DRAW_PENDING
09-27 23:10:08.213 24667-24667/com.ubcma.leadster D/GoalsRecyclerViewAdapter: adapter initialized
09-27 23:10:08.214 24667-24667/com.ubcma.leadster D/ViewRootImpl@14dce6f[GoalsActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
09-27 23:10:08.214 24667-24667/com.ubcma.leadster D/ViewRootImpl@14dce6f[GoalsActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
09-27 23:10:08.225 1606-1917/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.ubcma.leadster/.activity.GoalsActivity: +153ms
09-27 23:10:08.229 24667-24667/com.ubcma.leadster D/GoalsRecyclerViewAdapter: getItemCount: 2
09-27 23:10:08.229 24667-24667/com.ubcma.leadster D/GoalsRecyclerViewAdapter: getItemCount: 2
09-27 23:10:08.230 24667-24667/com.ubcma.leadster D/GoalsRecyclerViewAdapter: getItemCount: 2
09-27 23:10:08.230 24667-24667/com.ubcma.leadster D/GoalsRecyclerViewAdapter: onCreateViewHolder: inside
09-27 23:10:08.233 24667-24667/com.ubcma.leadster D/GoalsRecyclerViewAdapter: onBindViewHolder: position 0
09-27 23:10:08.234 24667-24667/com.ubcma.leadster D/GoalsRecyclerViewAdapter: bind: Goal{id=1, goalType='r', goalTitle='Recruit', goalFrequency='Month', goalTarget=12}
09-27 23:10:08.247 1606-12625/? D/WindowManager: finishDrawingWindow: Window{94ca436d0 u0 com.ubcma.leadster/com.ubcma.leadster.activity.GoalsActivity} mDrawState=HAS_DRAWN
```

Comment: I have my doubts about the layout_height being match_parent, have you tried checking if the item is shown by setting a background color to that relative layout?

Comment: @diedu after adding the background color to the relative layout, I was able to see that the view for the item was taking up the entire screen. How do you know when to use wrap_content or match_parent in recyclerview? It is really hard to tell. or in nested child views

Comment: Why you add this app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior".?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keeping height of recycler item as match_parent shows only one view per screen.Change your recycler item height from match_parent to wrap_content.

Also remove app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior".

Check this updated code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/calls_goal_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="23sp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:text="sample"
/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/goal_count"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:textSize="23sp"
    tools:text="4"/>
```

Comment: If it only shows 1 item on the screen, shouldn't I at least see the label textview?

Comment: omg that was it. can you explain why that took the entire screen? I thought that the height for the view itself.

Comment: yes the height of the view itself was causing problembeacuse you had given it as match_parent which results in each item of recycler view taking full screen...Also  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" this was unnecessary code.

Answer (score 19):

You need to specify layout manager before setting an adapter in recyclerview  like following

```
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

or Specify in the layout like following

```
app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
```

Comment: Okay, But then also try programmatically and remove from XML may be the doing issue sometime in XML.

Answer (score 4):

The **LayoutManager** most interesting part of a RecyclerView. This object tells the RecyclerView when to recycle objects that have transitioned off-screen and where they can go. This was formerly done solely by the ListView. This feature has been separated from the RecyclerView to allow for a variety of layouts: vertical, horizontal, grid, phased, or your own!

**LinearLayoutManager** arranges objects in a way that resembles a regular ListView.

**GridLayoutManager**, like a GridView, arranges objects in a grid style.

**StaggeredGridLayoutManager** arranges items in a staggered grid format.

You can add layoutmanager something like below

Kotlin

```
var linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
recycler.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
```

Java

```
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

Answer (score 3):

Set `android:visibility="visible"` in your `RecyclerView` xml code

Change

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/goals_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:dividerHeight="1px"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />
```

To

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/goals_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:dividerHeight="1px"
    android:visibility="visible"
    />
```

**Edit**

Add layoutManager to the code .

```
goalsListView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

And remove `app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"` in the xml code .

Comment: recyclerview will be set to visible if there is data in the list, if there is no data the text view will be displayed.